# exFAT missing from /proc/filesystems

Tags: partitioning, kernel, filesystem, exfat

One of the new features of Ubuntu 20.04 is kernel support for exFAT. It's my understanding that:

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

should list all the filesystems that the running kernel can support. When I use the above command I get a nice long list of filesystems but it does not include exFAT. Have I misunderstood  what is shown by this command?

I am running 20.04 with the 5.4.0_31 kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the new exFAT kernel driver was in Staging in 5.4 and fully released in 5.7.

See:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/linux-5-4-kernel-release-features
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/linux-5-7-kernel-features

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. What is the significance of it being in staging? Is that like a different version of the kernel that you can get by taking a particular action?